ElasticSearch Nest missed InnerHits data
I trying to get data from nested field (using Inner hits)
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {},
            "path": "physical_info_list",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "physical_info_list.name": {
                        "query": "Some name"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}




When I did it in kibana - it returns t data in the inner hits node (source).
But, when I use NEST in c#.
Field Source is empty
enter image description here

.Query(nestedQuery => nestedQuery
 .Bool(nestedBool => nestedBool
 .Must(nestedMustMatches.ToArray())))
.InnerHits(dt=>dt.Source(
                          s=>s.Includes(incl => incl.Fields(
                                                   "physical_info_list.hash_name",
                                                   "physical_info_list.name")
                          )));

Maybe I missed something? Please, maybe you have any ideas?
Thanks

Can you please try to remove source from innerHits and check. it seems like fields which you provided are not available and it is returning empty source.
